# Is it normal to store large pieces of HTML-code in properties file?

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I need to store a quietly big piece of HTML-code as a static resource. Is it normal to put it into properties file? Or would it be better if it stored in separate HTML-file? Storing in properties file seems to be more convenient since Spring has build-in mechanism to work with it, but I'm not sure this is a good approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have *never* seen HTML in a `.properties` file.  I cannot think of any problem where this would be a solid solution.

Put that HTML where it belongs: in an HTML file or a template of some kind.  Not a `.properties` file.

Answer (score 3):

How about using freemarker, a Java template engine, spring also can process it easily.
here is the [freemarker.org](http://freemarker.org/)

Answer (score 0):

See http://mixer2.org .
Mixer2 can use *.html template files in classpath with other resource files such as *.xml, *.properties.
You need not to store html tag into *.properties file.